# I am confused about Maui Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, maui

I have a DashBoardPage with it's own ViewModel. The page contains multiple ContentViews that also have their own ViewModels. The DashBoardPage xaml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <ContentPage
    x:Class="MPos.Views.DashboardPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:content="clr-namespace:MPos.Views.ContentViews"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MPos.Controls"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MPos.ViewModels"
    x:DataType="vm:DashboardViewModel">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <!--  Page Container  -->
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="100, .5*, .5*" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <controls:ButtonbarView Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            <content:ItemGalleryView Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            <content:ReceiptView Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </Grid>

    </StackLayout>

 </ContentPage>
```

My DashboardViewModel is empty (for now) but looks like this:

```
namespace MPos.ViewModels;

public partial class DashboardViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

}
```

The constructor for my ItemGalleryView looks like this:

```
   public ItemGalleryView(ItemGalleryViewModel viewModel)
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       BindingContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }
```

In my MauiProgram.cs file, I register both the ViewModels and the Views like this:

```
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<DashboardViewModel>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<DashboardPage>();

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ItemGalleryViewModel>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ItemGalleryView>();




    builder.Services.AddSingleton<CheckoutViewModel>();

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<CheckoutPage>();
```

I get two build errors -

> Error XLS0507 Type 'ItemGalleryView' is not usable as an object
> element because it is not public or does not define a public
> parameterless constructor or a type converter.

and

> Error XFC0004 Missing default constructor for
> "MPos.Views.ContentViews.ItemGalleryView".

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is clear. Your `ItemGalleryView` has not a default constructor so you can't use it in XAML in this way. You can make `BindableProperty` on your view or just bind your view model to `BindingContext`.

Remove the current constructor from ItemGalleryView and inject your `ItemGalleryViewModel` in `DashboardViewModel`.

```
public partial class DashboardViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
      public ItemGalleryViewModel GalleryViewModel { get; }
     
      public DashboardViewModel(ItemGalleryViewModel itemGaleryViewModel)
      {
         GalleryViewModel = itemGaleryViewModel
      }
}
```

Then you can bind it in XAML

```
<content:ItemGalleryView Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BindingContext={Binding  GalleryViewModel} />
```

If your `DashBoardPage` is `MainPage` of your app you can inject directly the `DashboardPage` (because you register it) into `App.cs` like

```
 public App(DashBoardPage page)
 {
     MainPage = page;
 }
```

or you can inject `DashboardViewModel` and make an instance of `DashboardPage` in `App.cs`

```
 public App(DashboardViewModel vm)
 {
     MainPage = new DashboardPage(vm);
 }
```